# Using perf command for an application which reads input file

Tags: performance, bash, perf

Some applications read input file via `<` character. For example,

```
./run_rog < input.txt
```

However passing the input file in such a way is invalid for `perf` command.

```
perf stat -e instructions ./run_prog < input.txt
Failed opening logfd: Invalid argument
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [source](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1206.2/00849.html)

> When running perf-stat in certain shell environments with stdout
>   redirection there is a logging file descriptor setup failure:
>
> `Failed opening logfd: Invalid argument`

Apparently, the perf tool needs applying a patch for solving this issue.

PS: Tried reproducing your problem with:

```
$ > perf --version
perf version 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64.debug
```

Got no issue:

```
$ > echo 'Test my perf' > input.txt
$ > perf stat -e instructions cat < input.txt
Test my perf

Performance counter stats for 'cat':

       580,283 instructions              #    0.00  insns per cycle

   0.003284129 seconds time elapsed
```

Comment: So, if I manually modify the source file `tools/perf/builtin-stat.c`, should I rebuild the kernel?

Comment: I have never (re)built the perf tool by myself, but I assume that, since builtin-stat.c is purely a userspace file, patching this file wouldn't affect the kernel at all. I would try using the sources, Makefile and guidance present [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/tools/perf). What linux distro are you using?

Comment: Maybe you should try updating the distro package which perf is contained in (e.g. "linux-tools" for Ubuntu).

Comment: My kernel is 2.6.32-279.5.1.el6.x86_64. OK I got it.

Answer (score 1):

There is hope somehere: this works for me on openSUSE 13.2 with perf 3.16.4.  The two commands

```
echo 'This is the input file' > input.txt
perf stat -e instructions /usr/bin/cat < input.txt
```

yields the output

```
This is the input file

 Performance counter stats for '/usr/bin/cat':

         1,181,541      instructions             

       0.000597226 seconds time elapsed
```